# Displaying data from MongoLab in my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mongodb, mlab

I can't seem to figure out a simple way to get data from MongoLab and display using HTML or Javascript or JQuery or whatever. I've looked at their REST API and everything and I still can't figure out how it works. Help please? From connecting to mongolab, getting the JSON, assigning it to some variable for displaying. I know this is supposed to be easy, there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at

[REST API](http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/) and
[Getting started with mongolab](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2530-Getting-Started-With-MongoLab-And-The-MongoDB-Shell.htm)?

If you are using Mongolab on azure see [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-mongolab-web-sites-nodejs-store-data-mongodb/).

And for Mongolab on Heroku look at [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry for being stupid. Uhm. I used the "Getting started with mongolab article" and I tried running the JS on my browser. It said "Mongo is not defined". I have mongodb on my machine via the brew thing. Yep, missing something.

Comment: I ran it using the mongo shell and it worked. How do I get it running on the browser?